# Websocket on Tomcat 7.0.39 on openshift

Tags: java, websocket, tomcat7, openshift

I've just successfully installed Apache Tomcat 7.0.39 on my openshift account (tomcat-ngoanhtuanthesis.rhcloud.com/). I know that tomcat 7.0.39 has supported Websocket. In my local computer, I can run my web socket aplication properly, but I cannot run it in the openshift server. However, my web service application can run very well. I've searched over the Internet for the whole week but I couldn't find any solution. Can anyone help me? Thank you in advance!

Note: here is my Web service:

tomcat-ngoanhtuanthesis.rhcloud.com/TrueTrafficServerAlpha2/

And here are some websocket examples integrated in Tomcat 7.0.39. These examples cannot run even though they are very simple.

http://tomcat-ngoanhtuanthesis.rhcloud.com/examples/websocket/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you read this? https://www.openshift.com/blogs/paas-websockets

WebSockects are currently under staging on openshift, and are available on alternative ports.

> **How to access Preview WebSockets Support?**
>
> You will need to connect to
>   specific ports, as the main routing layer is still Apache based and
>   does not support WebSockets.
>
> So, for plain WebSockets ws:// you will use port 8000 and for secured
>   connections wss:// port 8443. Here's an example:
>
> > http://app-lovingwebsockets.rhcloud.com/  <= your current HTTP URL
> >
> > http://app-lovingwebsockets.rhcloud.com:8000/ <= WebSockets enables HTTP URL
> >
> > https://app-lovingwebsockets.rhcloud.com/  <= your current HTTPs URL
> >
> > https://app-lovingwebsockets.rhcloud.com:8443/ <= WebSockets enables HTTPs URL

So, just open your samples here, and they will just work (hopefully):

```
https://tomcat-ngoanhtuanthesis.rhcloud.com:8443/examples/websocket/
```